# WiFi connection is -always- limited connectivity for every network/router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-driver

I have a Lenovo v570 with a Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 card and running windows 7 home premium 64bit. Every time I connect to a wireless network it says connection unsuccessful, and that I have limited access. The connection usually still works and I can browse the web and download/upload fine. I tried re-installing the driver, changing the power settings, and it still has the problem.